# Asy graph problem ---- call of function 'xaxis ..... is ambiguous

Tags: graphics, asymptote

```
unitsize(1cm);
defaultpen(linewidth(.8pt)+fontsize(8pt));

fill((2/3,0)--(3,3)--(3,1)--(2,1)--(2,0)--cycle,gray);

xaxis("$x$",-0.5,4,EndArrow(HookHead,4));
yaxis("$y$",-0.5,4,EndArrow(4));

draw((0,1)--(3,1)--(3,3)--(2,3)--(2,0));
draw((1,0)--(1,2)--(3,2));
draw((2/3,0)--(3,3));

label("$(c,0)$",(2/3,0),S);
label("$(3,3)$",(3,3),NE);
```

Copied from here

```
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2009_AMC_10B_Problems&action=edit&section=17
```

When compiled，I got an error:

> > call of function 'xaxis(string, int, int, bool(picture, path, pen, marginT(path, pen)))' is ambiguous

And my output, which is missing the axis...
[image]

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks.

**Update on 05 Jan 2021 **

Hmmmmm, maybe I need to re-do my whole MikTeX and Asy distributions...
[image]
Adding `import graph;` does not change anything ...

Comment: hmmmmmmm I added it, but the same problem. It's not showing the axis...@NguyenVanChi

Comment: @NguyenVanChi hmmmmmmm very weird.....I tried to Google the problem, but didn't find any solution. I have also reinstalled ASY too.... I will upload my ouput in a sec...

Comment: @NguyenVanChi How do you get 2.69 version? I am using 2.68 and X86. Does it matter?

Comment: @NguyenVanChi hmmmm, still the same problem, on multiple machines...

Comment: all you need is just adding `import graph;` at the beginning of the code (in order to Asymptote understands `xaxis`, `yaxis` commands)

Answer (score 1):

You just add `import graph;` at the beginning of the code, so Asymptote understands `xaxis`, `yaxis` commands). I modify your code a bit.

[image]

```
import graph;
unitsize(1cm);

real c=2/3;
filldraw((c,0)--(3,3)--(3,1)--(2,1)--(2,0)--cycle,lightyellow);
draw((0,1)--(3,1)--(3,3)--(2,3)--(2,0)--(1,0)--(1,2)--(3,2));

label(scale(.6)*"$(c,0)$",(c,0),S);
label(scale(.6)*"$(3,3)$",(3,3),N);

xaxis("$x$",-.5,4,EndArrow(TeXHead));
yaxis("$y$",-.5,4,EndArrow(TeXHead));

add(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Also, without using `graph` module, you can draw axes directly.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);

real c=2/3;
filldraw((c,0)--(3,3)--(3,1)--(2,1)--(2,0)--cycle,lightcyan);
draw((0,1)--(3,1)--(3,3)--(2,3)--(2,0)--(1,0)--(1,2)--(3,2));

label(scale(.6)*"$(c,0)$",(c,0),S);
label(scale(.6)*"$(3,3)$",(3,3),N);

draw(Label("$x$",align=SW,EndPoint),(-.5,0)--(4,0),Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(Label("$y$",align=SW,EndPoint),(0,-.5)--(0,4),Arrow(TeXHead));

add(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: your first code with ``import graph;`` still won't work on my system, maybe it's MikTeX's problem...I will re-install both to see what's the real problem...

Comment: @CasperYC I run it on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/